# animate from left to right and right to left

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a problem with css3 animate; 
I have two animations : one on top and one on bottom.
The top animation will load from 0 width to 100% and it works great but the second animation should load from 0 to 100% width from right to left and is not working :( Can someone explain me why ?
**[here is my fiddle exaple:](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/6256/)**

```
.left-to-right {animation:myfirst 1s ease;}
.right-to-left {animation:mysecond 1s ease;}

@keyframes myfirst {
  0%   {width:0; margin-left:100%;}
    100% {width: 100%; margin-left: 0;}
}
@keyframes mysecond {
  0%   {width:100%; margin-left: 0;}
    100% {width: 0; margin-left:100%;}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a mistake on the margins for the second animation. You can remove them :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/6257/)**

```
@keyframes mysecond {
    0%   {width:0;}
    100% {width: 100%;}
}
```